# Application_Error() not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET application that logs exceptions to the database. I'm using Application_Error to catch the exception.

Before adding the connection string, just to test my code (Logger class and the code in Global.asax), I tried to log the error to windows event viewer. This works as expected.

But after adding the connection string to the Web.config file and adding the ADO.NET code, I tried to run the application. But I get the yellow screen of death :D

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I only modified the connectionStrings element in the Web.config file and added the ADO.NET code.

Here is the code.

This is the web form code in the Page_Load event. The Countries.xml file is not present and it is expected to throw an error.

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
dataset.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Countries.xml"));
GridView1.DataSource = dataset;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Application_Error

```
Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
if (exception != null)
{
Logger.Log(exception);
Server.ClearError();
Server.Transfer("~/Errors.aspx");
}
```

Web.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=.;database=Sample;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I tried debugging by placing a breakpoint at the Application_Error method in Global.asax, but the control never reaches to that point.
The exception is triggered from the Page_Load event.
There are no compilation errors in the Logger class code.
Also, I don't want to use the customErrors route to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

This is the link to the code:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5K22Q9r50wXU0VOQmJKVHBoaDg&usp=sharing

Comment: Are you implementing a custom error page too? Have you verified that you have no other try-catch statements that possible caught the exception first before your Application_Error code?

Comment: Hi @Ephraim, yes I am implementing a custom error page: Errors.aspx. There is no other try catch block in my code. The exception is not getting handled and I see the yellow screen of death.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `<customErrors mode="Off" />` while ***debugging***, the code won't reach to `Application_Error` event because exception is displayed inside browser right away.

If you want to reach Application_Error while debugging, you want to enable custom error -

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" />
```

Comment: Hi @Win, I tried that. But the control never reaches Application_Error method. Although I do get redirected to the Errors.aspx page

Comment: yep, what the heck is Application_Error for then

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled custom errors on the web.config?

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Errors.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Note that the redirect mode is 'ResponseRewrite' in-order to preserve the `Server.GetLastError()` exception. If you set this otherwise then `Server.GetLastError()` will return null.

Implementing Application_Error should be easy.. in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex is ThreadAbortException)
        return; // Redirects may cause this exception..
    Logger.Error(LoggerType.Global, ex, "Exception");
    Response.Redirect("unexpectederror.htm");
}
```

UPDATE:

A possible culprit would be the HandlerErrorAttribute registered as filter on the Global.asax.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); // this line is the culprit
}
```

Simply comment out or remove the line and make sure you have implemented the customErrors in the system.web under web.config.

I'm not that familiar with the HandleErrorAttribute, if this resolves your issue then might as well look up its documentation.

Comment: Hi @Ephraim, you approach will work and this will help me catch the exception. But then what is wrong with the code and approach I'm using, is my question. The Application_Error should get fired when the exception is not handled using either a try-catch block or at the page level. So why is that not working?

Comment: @Nachiket I updated my answer. Probably your method signature for Application_Error is incorrect somewhere. I posted an example.

Comment: No the method signature is the same. I tried your code. But the control won't reach to Application_Error method. I even changed the value of the customErrors mode from remoteOnly to on, but still no change. I mean I get directed to the Errors.aspx page, but the Application_Error is not fired.

Comment: @Nachiket I have updated my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Ephraim I don't have this method in my code. This is a link to my code. If you can go through the code, it will be easier to identify the error. [link] https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5K22Q9r50wXU0VOQmJKVHBoaDg&usp=sharing

Comment: @Nachiket you want to view the log in event viewer right? what is the source you specified for logging? It should be an existing source. Probably your logging failed. Please check and verify.

Comment: I tried to log the errors to windows event viewer and it worked as expected. Then I replaced this code with ADO.NET to log the error to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had error logging (sentry.io) inside this event handler and the logging algorithm caused error itself thus redirecting to error pages defined inside the web.config and I also thought it isn't firing. Make sure you use try-catch for your code inside the error handler too in order to debug the case. Ie. flush exception details as response and end the response.

Here is my error logger to sentry.io:

```
public static void LogException(Exception ex, bool redirect = true)
{
    if (ex != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        // ignore Response.Redirect errors
        if (ex.GetType() == typeof(ThreadAbortException))
        {
            return;
        }

        var sentryApiKey = GetAppSetting("SentryIO.ApiKey");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentryApiKey))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("SentryIO.ApiKey not defined as app setting.");
        }

        var ravenClient = new RavenClient(sentryApiKey);
        ravenClient.Capture(new SentryEvent(ex));

        if (redirect)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/?500-error-logged");
        }
    }
}
```

As I see building in release mode or having web.config like below, doesn't prevent this event from firing.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="errordocs/500.htm">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="errordocs/403.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="errordocs/404.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that `endResponse` was set to `false`.

I changes from `false` to `true` and it solved the issue:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect($"/e/{errorId}", true);
```